# Swift: App needs to open Apple Maps when Google Maps not installed

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-maps, apple-maps

I have built an app for the Copenhagen bikers but have some trouble.
The app needs to open Apple maps when Google Maps is not available on the phone.

The code looks like this

```
// OUTLETS!
@IBOutlet weak var googleMapsView: GMSMapView!

// VARIABLES!
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var M1: GMSMarker!
var M2: GMSMarker!

    //Marker funtioncs
var markerFunctions: [GMSMarker: (() -> Void)]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // GET LOCATION WHILE USING APP
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

    initGoogleMaps()
}

// START GOOGLE MAPS!
func initGoogleMaps() {

    // MARKERS
    M1 = GMSMarker()
    M1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 55.65208178045790, longitude: 12.527047696518300)
    M1.title = "Sjælør St."
    M1.snippet = "Press for navigation"
    M1.map = self.googleMapsView

    M2 = GMSMarker()
    M2.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 55.67530850095370, longitude: 12.583165039072400)
    M2.title = "Børsen (Slotsholmsgade)"
    M2.snippet = "Press for navigation"
    M2.map = self.googleMapsView

        // Marker functions
    markerFunctions = [
        M1: { UIApplication.shared.open(NSURL(string: "comgooglemaps-x-callback://" +
            "?daddr=55.65208178045790,12.527047696518300&directionsmode=bicycling&zoom=17")! as URL)},

        M2: { UIApplication.shared.open(NSURL(string: "comgooglemaps-x-callback://" +
            "?daddr=55.67530850095370,12.583165039072400&directionsmode=bicycling&zoom=17")! as URL)},
```

When tapping the Info-window, navigation for Google Maps needs to appear (it works). However, if the Google Maps app is not available, how do I re-write the "Marker Functions" so it will open i Apple Maps instead?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html ? Check "canOpenURL()" to know which one is available.

Answer (score 7):

To do this, you will need to check whether Google Maps is installed. This can be done fairly easy:

```
func openMaps(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees) {
    let googleMapsInstalled = UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "comgooglemaps://")!)
    if googleMapsInstalled {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "comgooglemaps-x-callback://" +
            "?daddr=\(latitude),\(longitude)&directionsmode=bicycling&zoom=17")!)
    } else {
        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
        mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: nil)
    }
}
```

Per default iOS does not allow checking whether an URL can be opened for privacy reasons. You need to whitelist checking for `comgooglemaps://` in your app. To do this add this to your apps `Info.plist`:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
```

If you have done this correctly `openMaps(latitude:, logitude:)` will open Google Maps if it is installed, otherwise it will open Apple Maps. Just change your closures ("Marker Functions") to call the new method.

Of course you will also need to `import MapKit` for this to work.

Comment: @nagleer 
Thank you very much for your quick response. I have looked at it but it does not work because I need the function to work for several InfoWindows. For example, if you tab InfoWindow#1 then directions to XXXX but if you tab InfoWindow#2 then directions to YYYY. Do you know how to write your code to function for different InfoWindow-tabs?

Comment: Did you try to read and understand my function? It already does that. It takes coordinates and shows whatever location you give it.
Also, you did not tell as about `InfoWindow` in your question and did not mention what those `InfoWindow`s are. Based on the information available, I can not help you any futher. You will need to clarify what you are trying to do. Also, please check my example again as I suspect it already does what you want it to do.